# Using window.onbeforeunload with page.js

Tags: reactjs, history, pushstate

I'm trying to add a `window.onbeforeunload` listener to my web app. I'm using [page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/) as my client side router. Due to pushstate, `onbeforeunload` is not working. Even if I try some work around, the page stays but the url changes. How to make it work?

Comment: Are you using page.js with React? Attach code to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `page.exit(path,function(ctx,next){})`

In this you can handle before unload logic.